# Get Gravity Forms field values and count how many?

Tags: count, php, plugin-gravity-forms

I don't know how to explain this the best way. But, I am using a form in Gravity Forms for rating something 0 - 10. In the code below, I can get the results. However, I need to see how many ratings are 0-6 and how many ratings are 9-10. I have it so I can see the results and tell if it's "Negative", "Neutral", or "Positive" feedback. I need a count of "Negative" and "Positive" then pass those into the `$neg_fb` and `$pos_fb` variables, respectively. Hope this makes some sense.

```
<?php
    // The form's ID
        $form_id = 7;

    // Total Number of Entries
        $form_count  = RGFormsModel::get_form_counts($form_id);
        $entry_total = $form_count['total'];
        echo '<p>Number of entries: <strong>' . $entry_total . '</strong></p>';

    // Get Entry Values
        $entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form_id);
        foreach($entries as $entry){
            if($entry[1] < 7){
                echo $entry[1] . ' = Negative Feedback<hr>';
            }elseif($entry[1] > 8){
                echo $entry[1] . ' = Positive Feedback<hr>';
            }else{
                echo $entry[1] . ' = Neutral Feedback<hr>';
            }
        }

    // NPS Variables
        $pos_fb = 2;
        $neg_fb = 1;
    // NPS Formula
        $nps    = ($pos_fb / $entry_total) - ($neg_fb / $entry_total);
    // Multiply for percentage
        $perct  = ($nps * 100);
    // Round up
        $whole  = ceil($perct);
    // Display whole percentage
        echo '<h4>' . $whole . '% NPS Recommendation</h4>';
?>
```

Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set two variables to 0 before the foreach loop.
$positive = 0;
$negative = 0;

Then in your if statement:

```
if($entry[1] < 7){


//increment variable
$negative++;

 echo $entry[1] . ' = Negative Feedback<hr>';
 }elseif($entry[1] > 8){ 

//increment variable 
$positive++

echo $entry[1] . ' = Positive Feedback<hr>'; }else{ echo $entry[1] . ' = Neutral Feedback<hr>'; }
```

Use the results as need.

Comment: Thank you!! I had tried something similar before but I set the variables to 0 inside of the foreach statement.